# Need help locating element with XPath

Tags: xpath

I am learning about xpath , can you help me go to the "i class" tag and click on reddit's up vote icon. I tried to find the comment text

[image]

I can connect the paragraph

```
//div[contains(p/text(),'The user name completes this')]
```

and find the up vote icon tag right below this comment

https://www.reddit.com/r/me_irl/comments/zg7nr5/comment/izgy4a3/?utm_source=reddit&utm_medium=web2x&context=3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can locate the parent `div` block of the entire comment by the text content and then go to upvote button inside it as following:

```
"//div[contains(.,'The user name completes this')][contains(@class,'Comment')]//button[@aria-label='upvote']"
```

I'm not sure you really need that `i` icon element so I gave the locator of the upvote button.
In case you really need the `i` element inside it - it can be located similarly as following

```
"//div[contains(.,'The user name completes this')][contains(@class,'Comment')]//i[contains(@class,'upvote')]"
```

Answer (score 0):

Like this:

```
//div[contains(.,'The user name completes this')]//button[@data-click-id='upvote']
```